# Sufficient Statistic for inverse Gaussian Distribution

Tags: self-study, sufficient-statistics, arithmetic, inverse-gaussian-distribution

> Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample from population with the pdf of
>   the inverse Gaussian distribution
>
> $$f(x|\theta,\beta)=(\frac{\beta}{2 \pi
>  x^3})^\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{\beta(x-\theta)^2}{2\theta^2 x}}$$ where $
>  0<x<\infty$
>
> a) Find the sufficient statistic for $\theta$ and $\beta$ b) Find the
>   MLE of $\theta$ and $\beta$

So to find be, I need the joint pdf first and use the factorization theorem

$f(\textbf{x}|\theta,\beta)=g(T(\textbf{x})|\theta,\beta)h(x),$ where T(x) is the sufficient statistic

So obviously the left part with the $x^3$ will resolve out to h(x), but the right portion is where I'm having trouble

$\Pi_i^n e^{-\frac{\beta(x-\theta)^2}{2\theta^2 x}}=e^{-\frac{\beta}{2\theta^2}\Sigma_i^n\frac{(x_i-\theta)^2}{x_i}} $

This might be more of an arithmetic question, but I'm having trouble isolating out the x's so I can get a T(x). Let me know if I'm going wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Hint: $T(X)$ does not have to involve $X$. It can also be a constant.

Comment: But it can't be reliant on $\beta$ or $\theta$ right? So that woudl just leave something with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$ or $e^{-.5}$ then